# Can't listen on Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create linear progress indicator which shows in percentage progress of uploading file.
I used this tutorial: https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-show-download-progress-in-a-flutter-app-8810e294acbd

The problem is that, **anything which should be listened, is executed after uploading**.
Function to listen (but it doesn't):

```
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('image.jpg');
      ref.putFile(image).asStream().listen((event) {
        progress = event.bytesTransferred / event.totalBytes;
        notifyListeners();
      });
```

Here is my full code:

```
class Idk extends ChangeNotifier {
  double progress = 0;
  get downloadProgress => progress;

  startUploading() async {
    PickedFile _image =
        await ImagePicker().getVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    File image = File(_image.path);
    notifyListeners();
    if (image != null) {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('image.jpg');
      ref.putFile(image).asStream().listen((event) {
        progress = event.bytesTransferred / event.totalBytes;
        notifyListeners();
      });
    }
  }
}

class Indicator extends StatelessWidget {
  getPicFromGallery() async {
    PickedFile _image =
        await ImagePicker().getVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    File image = File(_image.path);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelProvider<Idk>.withConsumer(
        viewModel: Idk(),
        builder: (context, model, child) => Column(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => model.startUploading(),
                    child: Text('add to firebase')),
                Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    value: model.downloadProgress,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ));
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use a StreamBuilder to update your CircularProgressIndicator and try to print the value inside .listen to check if the stream is null. You can find many tutorials online on how to use Streams.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Passing UploadTask to the next screen which shows progress of uploading

```
 Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Uploading(
                FirebaseStorage.instance
                    .ref()
                    .child('screenshots')
                    .putFile(file),
                )));
```

Creating variable progress, using StreamBuilder and its feature snapshot:

```
class Uploading extends StatelessWidget {
  UploadTask uploadTask;
  Uploading(this.uploadTask);

  double progress(TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: uploadTask.snapshotEvents,
        builder: (
          context,
          asyncSnapshot,
        ) {
          TaskSnapshot snapshot = asyncSnapshot.data;
          if (uploadTask.snapshot.state == TaskState.running) {
            if (snapshot != null) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text('adding post'),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          value: progress(snapshot),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
          }
        });
  }
}
```